# Get the "Active Configuration"

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

is there an way to get the "Active Configuration" (Debug / Release) with ObjC or the iOS SDK ?

Comment: You mean programmatically within your app?

Comment: @onnoweb: yes, programmatically!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy way

```
bool isDebug = NO;
#ifdef DEBUG
 isDebug = YES;  
#endif
```

What do you mean by getting it?
This example will set the variable at compile time which can be use to check if it's a debug build or not in the program.

Comment: I found a solution with Preprocessor Macros in 'clingingtoideas' Blog:
http://clingingtoideas.blogspot.com/2009/08/it-nslog-nslog.html

Comment: You have to add -DDEBUG in the "Other C Flags" section under "Build Phase"

Comment: @meccan, I'm sorry I forgot to tell you to add a flag to the compiler. Please refer to @Francis McGrew answer.